# Bootstrap Collapse opens in both directons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

following issue:

I tried to rebuild a table with `div` elements so I could use Metafizzy Isotope to filter them. So far so good. In each row there is a button which opens / closes an attached accordion / collapse. The collapse should slide open up from top to bottom, so it did with two rows and so it did with two `li` elements. But to keep the sorting up I had to stuff my collapse into my first `li` element. And that's when the collapse started to push the `div` elements above to the top until there is no space left and then going down until it has fully opened.

https://codepen.io/paulhaem/pen/ZJELJr

Thanks for any suggestions on how to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently center the content in the row with `min-height: 60px; align-items: center;`. But if you expand the collapse element, the height of your content increases beyond 60px and therefore your collapse element goes up as well. With your current markup and styling, you could solve the issue by providing a `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to the `grid-item__line`. Something like

```
li.grid-item__line {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bototm: 14px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem. Nice explanation! :-)